# The request payloads from Google Home iOS app were incorrect

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I am developing an IOT system integrating with Google Home. The device has two features: night mode control and auto mode control.

It displayed correctly on both Android and iOS with two buttons toggling the night mode and the auto mode. The problem is that on iOS Google Home pressing the auto mode button sends night mode request payloads for auto mode requests to our system. On Android Google Home it sent the correct auto mode request payloads.

I tried to print the logs in our system for the payloads from Google Home. Here are the intent execution payload logs to compare the iOS and the Android apps.

The payload from the iOS Google Home app, which you can see the command was for night mode toggling

```
{
    "body": "{\"inputs\":[{\"context\":{\"locale_country\":\"US\",\"locale_language\":\"en\"},\"intent\":\"action.devices.EXECUTE\",\"payload\":{\"commands\":[{\"devices\":[{\"customData\":{\"sku\":\"110403\"},\"id\":\"1446f14f-3bb6-43f3-8f05-53859aaeadc1\"}],\"execution\":[{\"command\":\"action.devices.commands.SetToggles\",\"params\":{\"updateToggleSettings\":{\"Night Mode\":false}}}]}]}}],\"requestId\":\"10491079152141754987\"}",
    "headers": {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Authorization": "Bearer ${deleted_for_security}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Google-Assistant-API-Version": "v1",
        "Host": "ychmmhbbi1.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-65488f67-1a60497e6f2670177b8b7f4d",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "74.125.215.227",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "multiValueHeaders": {
        "Accept-Encoding": [
            "gzip, deflate, br"
        ],
        "Authorization": [
            "Bearer ${deleted_for_security}"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "Google-Assistant-API-Version": [
            "v1"
        ],
        "Host": [
            "ychmmhbbi1.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "User-Agent": [
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
        ],
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
            "Root=1-65488f67-1a60497e6f2670177b8b7f4d"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-For": [
            "74.125.215.227"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Port": [
            "443"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
            "https"
        ]
    },
    "path": "/c/google",
    "requestContext": {
        "accountId": "186386129454",
        "apiId": "ychmmhbbi1",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "identity": {
            "sourceIp": "74.125.215.227",
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
        },
        "path": "/qa/c/google",
        "requestId": "4927cea8-e8e0-4dc9-8c77-a040a753cad7",
        "resourceId": "7r3y7w",
        "resourcePath": "/c/google",
        "stage": "qa"
    },
    "resource": "/c/google"
}
```

The auto mode intent execution payload from the Android Google Home App.

```
{
    "body": "{\"inputs\":[{\"context\":{\"locale_country\":\"US\",\"locale_language\":\"en\"},\"intent\":\"action.devices.EXECUTE\",\"payload\":{\"commands\":[{\"devices\":[{\"customData\":{\"sku\":\"110403\"},\"id\":\"1446f14f-3bb6-43f3-8f05-53859aaeadc1\"}],\"execution\":[{\"command\":\"action.devices.commands.SetToggles\",\"params\":{\"updateToggleSettings\":{\"Auto Mode\":true}}}]}]}}],\"requestId\":\"10073094688020598426\"}",
    "headers": {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Authorization": "Bearer ${deleted_for_security}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Google-Assistant-API-Version": "v1",
        "Host": "ychmmhbbi1.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-65488ef7-103826161c52a27831b7b827",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "74.125.215.231",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "multiValueHeaders": {
        "Accept-Encoding": [
            "gzip, deflate, br"
        ],
        "Authorization": [
            "Bearer ${deleted_for_security}"
        ],
        "Content-Type": [
            "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "Google-Assistant-API-Version": [
            "v1"
        ],
        "Host": [
            "ychmmhbbi1.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "User-Agent": [
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
        ],
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": [
            "Root=1-65488ef7-103826161c52a27831b7b827"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-For": [
            "74.125.215.231"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Port": [
            "443"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
            "https"
        ]
    },
    "path": "/c/google",
    "requestContext": {
        "accountId": "186386129454",
        "apiId": "ychmmhbbi1",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "identity": {
            "sourceIp": "74.125.215.231",
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
        },
        "path": "/qa/c/google",
        "requestId": "7e89042f-1a4b-47f7-991c-c9d7dfe87dc1",
        "resourceId": "7r3y7w",
        "resourcePath": "/c/google",
        "stage": "qa"
    },
    "resource": "/c/google"
}
```

How to make the iOS Google Home app send the correct auto mode intent execution payload just like the Android app?